# Update state from props in Searchbar with button React

Tags: reactjs, search, input, state, react-props

I have to do a classic searchbar with button. Button is important here, because I can display my list after clicking it, not earlier.

[image]

I made main component where searchbar with list are displayed.

```
class MonitorManagement extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context)

        this.state = {
            isInitialized: false,
            isSearchReady: false,
            searchString: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.handlers.onGetCaseMonitors()
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (!this.state.isInitialized && this.props.caseMonitors) {
            this.setState({
                caseMonitors: this.props.caseMonitors,
                isInitialized: true
            })
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.handlers.onClearCaseMonitors()
    }

    onSearch = searchString => {
        const { caseMonitors } = this.props

        const filtered = caseMonitors.filter(({ name }) =>
            name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
        )

        this.setState({ caseMonitors: filtered, isSearchReady: true })
    }

    onSearchHandler = () => {
        const { caseMonitors, handlers } = this.props
        const { searchString } = this.state

        this.setState({ isSearchReady: false })

        handlers.onGetCaseMonitors()

        if (caseMonitors) {
            handlers.onClearCaseMonitors()
        }

        if (searchString) {
            return this.onSearch(searchString)
        }

        this.setState({ isInitialized: false })
    }

    onSearchUpdate = searchString => this.setState({ searchString })

    renderSearch = () => {
        const { caseMonitors, searchString } = this.state

        return (
            <Search
                caseMonitors={caseMonitors}
                value={searchString}
                handlers={{
                    onSearchUpdate: this.onSearchUpdate,
                    onSearchHandler: this.onSearchHandler
                }}
            />
        )
    }

    renderList = () => {
        const { caseMonitors } = this.state

        if (!caseMonitors) {
            return <Spinner />
        }

        return (
            <List
                caseMonitors={caseMonitors}
            />
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderSearch()}
                {this.renderList()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is search component

```
export default class MonitorManagementSearch extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context)

        this.searchID = 'monitor-management'
    }

    renderSearch = () => (
        <Search
            handlers={{
                onChange: this.props.handlers.onSearchUpdate,
                onSubmit: this.props.handlers.onSearchHandler
            }}
            id={this.searchID}
            isDisabled={!this.props.caseMonitors}
            minLength={3}
            placeholder={i18n.t('toolkit:MONITOR_MANAGEMENT.PLACEHOLDER_SEARCH')}
            value={this.props.searchString} />
    )

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderSearch()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My solution works, but I'm not satisfied. I'd like to get rid of `isInitialized` flag. I had to do it because my props come from redux store and are null first time when component is mounted. I want to keep all search list in my state and display it in List component. But at the beginning is impossible, because it is equal to null.

Do you guys have some ideas how to improve?

Comment: Can't you check just for this.props.caseMonitors?

Comment: what if  you set your state variable something like  "var state = {isIntialized:false,...state}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a good practice to assign the props to state `caseMonitors: this.props.caseMonitors`

You can have a util `getFilteredData` , which does the following

1. when there is no search string , then just return the props.caseMonitors
2. when there is search string then filter the data .

```
renderList = () => {
  if (!props.caseMonitors) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  const filteredData= getFilteredData(props.caseMonitors, this.state.searchString);

  return <List caseMonitors={filteredData} />;
};
```

getFilteredData Util

```
const getFilteredData = (dataToFilter, searchText) => {
   if(searchText.trim().length === 0){
      return dataToFilter;
   }

    const filteredData = dataToFilter.filter(({ name }) =>
            name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
        )

   return filteredData ;
}
```

Your filteredData is just a derived state based on the state `searchString` and the props `cashMonitor` so it is not needed to maintain 2 states for them. You can remove the `componentDidUpdate` and also the `isInitialized` state as they are not needed .

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-moon-f7jtr?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: but it gives me searched list without using button. I need render list after clicking it, not before.

Comment: In that case you need to have a flag which sets the value for the button , what does the state 'isSearchReady' do ?

Comment: in the component above, it does actually nothing. But I'd like to use this flag for handler but no idea how ;( do you know?

Comment: Edited my answer with a working sandbox replicating the behaviour.

Comment: Shyam, thank you so much. It helps a bit, master :). But I've noticed one thing. If you found things from the list after clicking search button and then you are writing a additional letter... you get all list displayed again. It happens because onChange returns startSearch: false. I'd like to keep searched list till I click search button again. I mean when you are typing in search input you can't change displayed list. Displayed list can be updated only after clicking on button. Could you help to achieve that?

Comment: ok so the question now here is , if i type something and click on search i will show the filtered list . now if i type again , should i filter on top of this filtered list or the entire list ?

Comment: Definitely, entire list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236406/discussion-between-shyam-and-karolina-szlenk).

Comment: Updated the sandbox . Please check .